# Square root inside a square root python

Tags: python, square-root

I was wondering how to write a code showing the square root inside a square root. This is what I have so far:

```
number=float(input("Please enter a number: "))
square = 2*number**(1/2)**(1/3)
print(square)
```

But that's not right as I'm getting a different number from the calculator.

Comment: Raising something to the (1/3) is the cube root, not the square root. (a^(1/2))^(1/2) is equivalent to a^(1/4). So you could just do the fourth root.

Comment: Perhaps check your order of operations, what exactly are you trying to calculate? http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: What is python outputting, and what is your calculator outputting?  This will help indicate what your problem is.

Answer (score 4):

Import `math` and use `math.sqrt(math.sqrt(number))`

```
import math
number=float(input("Please enter a number: "))
square = math.sqrt(math.sqrt(number))
print(square)
```

Comment: Notice that one of them is a cube root

Comment: @DonaldMiner It's unclear if that was a mistake of the OP, or if their description is incorrect. If we go by the description, this is correct.  If we go by the code then we would need a cube root function.  Either way, the OP needs to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is doing the square root (i.e., `1/2`) of `1/3` and then applying that to `number`. You'll want to force the order of operations since it's evaluating the exponent operator from right to left.

```
square = 2*(number**(1/2))**(1/3)
```

By adding parenthesis, you are forcing it to take the square root first, and then the cube root.

---

You are using Python3, but for future readers, Python2 would evaluate `1/2` and `1/3` to `0`. To change that you'd use floats instead:

```
square = 2*(number**(1.0/2.0))**(1.0/3.0)
```

Comment: `1/2` and `1/3` are `0` in Python2.

Comment: He's using Python 3, obvious from the `print` statement. But yes, I'll elaborate for python2

Comment: @DonaldMiner It's not necessarily obvious, because they could be using `from __future__ import print_function` and not `from __future__ import division`

Comment: For a test run, I put in 1 and the answer is supposed to be 1.61887. I'm getting 2.0 as the answer.

Comment: Ok, so do the math: 2 x 1 ^ .5 ^ .33 is going to give you 2. (square root of 1 is 1, cube root of 1 is 1, times 2 is 2). Maybe you need to be more clear about what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: My guess is that they meant `(2*1)**.5**.33`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the square root of the square root of a number you can see using some algebra we can see that `((x)^0.5)^0.5)` simplifies down to `x^(0.25)`

So you can either do `x**(0.25)`

or you can do the following:

```
import math
math.sqrt(math.sqrt(x))
```

One other thing, in your code you say:

```
square = 2*number**(1/2)**(1/3)
```

and in the title you say "Square root inside a square root python". This indicates to me that you might have made either a typo in your code or mistake in naming the title of your question. If you do want to find a square root of a square root then my suggestions above should be sufficient to do that.

Comment: Notice that one of them is a cube root

Comment: Yes, I did see that, the question title and the description both talk about the square root of a square root and not a cube root so I assumed that was what was wanted. Just made an edit to my answer to address that.